# DataTable DataRow DataColumn for columns

Tags: .net, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I am dumping a cvs file into a datatable. I am able to loop through each row and each column. I only do run some some logic for 4 columns out of 16 columns. I tried if but not working. How do i use "for" type syntax? For example, I like to say for columnA do this. For columnB do this. (instead of if(column.ColumnName == "ColumnA") then do something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're stuck with testing the column name against some string value. Even if  someone comes up with a lambda expression, it's all essentially the same thing: looping and string comparisons.

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        switch (col.Name)
        {
            case "ColumnA":
                  // do something
                  // if(row[col.Name] = ??) { ... }
                  break;
            case "ColumnB":
                  // do something else
                  break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brad, I am going with your approach; it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you already know the name of the columns, then you can always refer to it by the following syntax:

```
tableObject.Columns[columnName]
```

and for a particular row:

```
tableObject.Rows[rowIndex][columnName]
```

Comment: Thanks HPS, I had already used Brad's method and it worked. Thanks Again for pitching in.